Error de ejecución de Spring Boot vació java 17 (usando el java 22)
En clase he tenido este fallo al ejecutar SpringBoot totalmente vacío, y en vez de ejecutar y mostrar el clásico cartelito de Spring, la ejecución me tira este mensaje. El profesor me dice que debo formatear el ordenador.
Estoy utilizando Windows 7 con NetBean 22 y exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec
Código: (Es el código que genera por defecto SpringBoot)
    package com.cursojavabackend.primeraApi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PrimeraApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PrimeraApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}

ERROR:

Get-Content : No se encuentra ning£n par metro que coincida con el
nombre del p
ar metro 'Raw'.
En l¡nea: 1 Car cter: 182
+ & {$scriptDir='C:\Users\WIN7\Documents\CLASE PROGRAMACION\SpringBoot Generado
s\primeraApi\primeraApi'; $script='mvnw.cmd'; icm -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]:
:Create((Get-Content -Raw <<<<  'C:\Users\WIN7\Documents\CLASE PROGRAMACION\Spr
ingBoot Generados\primeraApi\primeraApi\mvnw.cmd'))) -NoNewScope}
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBin
dingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
ands.GetContentCommand


Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me podáis dar.

Powershell en Win 11 no soporta parametro Raw, seguramente es la version

Hola Lord_Po, bienvenido, tal vez, si mostraras tu código, alguien podría ayudarte... te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo agregues en formato texto.

Gracias, ahora mismo.

Jorgesys Utilizo un windows 7.

Estás usando PowerShell en Windows 7 (probablemente es PowerShell 2), de acuerdo al mensaje de error

Get-Content : No se encuentra ning£n par metro que coincida con el
nombre del p ar metro 'Raw'.

Tu versión de PowerShell no soporta el parámetro -Raw (Get-Content -Raw) que es usado para leer todo el contenido de un archivo como una sola cadena
Puedes revisar la versiòn usando el comando:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

De acuerdo a la documentación de PowerShell , el parámetro -Raw se introdujo en la versión 3.0

-Raw : Ignora los caracteres de nueva línea y devuelve todo el
contenido de un archivo en una cadena con las nuevas líneas
conservadas. De forma predeterminada, los caracteres de nueva línea en
un archivo se utilizan como delimitadores para separar la entrada en
una matriz de cadenas. Este parámetro se introdujo en PowerShell
3.0.

Debes actualizar PowerShell a una nueva versiòn.

Tienes razón, estoy utilizando la versión 2.0. Voy a intentar actualizarla. Mil gracias.

Muchísimas gracias Jorgesys, luego de buscar y encontrar el WMF 4.0 (que está descatalogado en la página de windows) y lograr instalar el WMF 5.1, pude ejecutar el ejercicio con Spring Boot. Muchas gracias!!!!
